# How to rebuild index for NPM repositories in Nexus?

Tags: npm, nexus

We have an instance of Nexus 2.11.4-01 PRO running on a 64bit RHEL6 that hosts several types of repositories. Recently, all NPM repositories got corrupted somehow and any attempt to publish a NPM package using npm on Windows fails with the following error:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 500
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Programs\\nodejs-0.12.7\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Programs\\nodejs-0.12.7\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "publish"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! Unexpected token <
npm ERR! <html>
npm ERR!   <head>
npm ERR!     <title>500 - We reached max level of depth of SBTree but still found nothing, seems like tree is in corrupted state. You should rebuild index related to given query.</title>
npm ERR!     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://nexus:8081/nexus/favicon.png">
npm ERR!     <!--[if IE]>
npm ERR!     <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://nexus:8081/nexus/favicon.ico"/>
npm ERR!     <![endif]-->
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://nexus:8081/nexus/static/css/Sonatype-content.css?2.11.4-01" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
npm ERR!   </head>
npm ERR!   <body>
npm ERR!     <h1>500 - We reached max level of depth of SBTree but still found nothing, seems like tree is in corrupted state. You should rebuild index related to given query.</h1>
npm ERR!     <p>We reached max level of depth of SBTree but still found nothing, seems like tree is in corrupted state. You should rebuild index related to given query.</p>
npm ERR!   </body>
npm ERR! </html>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\somewhere\npm-debug.log
```

As the logs indicate,

> We reached max level of depth of SBTree but still found nothing, seems like tree is in corrupted state. You should rebuild index related to given query.

but I cannot find how to rebuild that index. I tried to "Repair Index", "Update Index", even to "Expire Cache" from the admin UI, with the app both "In Service" and "Out of Service" without any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the support team about this problem and they replied (quite fast, in about 10 mins) the following:

> To rebuild the index for npm:
>
> 1. Shut down nexus
> 2. Remove the contents of sonatype-work/nexus/db/npm
> 3. Restart
> 4. Schedule "Rebuild hosted npm metadata" tasks to run against your hosted npm repositories
>
> You don't need to do anything for proxy or group npm repositories,
>   these will just work after restart.

And it worked correctly afterwards.

PS: No affiliation or whatsoever.